# git does not commit the backend and the client files becaues they have another git repos inside if them

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github, heroku

I finished building the backend (using NodeJS), and the frontend (using ReactJS), but I put them in different repositories. Now, as I am going to deploy them, I arranged them in a specific structure as guided.

```
final-project
|
---backend <--- restful API
|
---the-tech-blog <--- react app
|
---README
```

I initialized a new git repository using git init, and I am trying to push everything to this one repository so I can deploy it to  Heroku. However, both of my files are committed empty because they have other git repositories inside them.

I read about git submodule and try to add them inside my files:

```
$ cd ./backend
$ git submodule add -b master https://github.com/MohamadHanafi/theTechBlog-backend

$ cd ..
$ cd ./the-tech-blog
$ git submodule add -b master https://github.com/MohamadHanafi/theTechBlog
```

I committed again in the main file (final-project), but again nothing changed.

Comment: You probably also copied the `.git` invisible folders inside those projects. If you want a completely new repository you can remove those folders using `rm -rf .git`. You will lose the connection to the original repositories! Only do this if you still have the git history somewhere online or you don't care about losing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+nested+repository

Comment: Why are you trying to create one repository? It is very common to deploy the front-end and the back-end separately.

Comment: @Kokodoko thank you! I think I will try that

Comment: @Chris as I was reading, I think it is more common for MERN applications to be deployed in one repository. I will check for deployment in two separate repositories